# Rails 3 validation in model failure

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a validate_completion method defined in my task.rb model. The Pseudo logic should be

```
if no hazards exist
  date_completed = Date.today
elsif any hazard exists with a risk_total > 1000
  date_completed = nil
else any hazard that exists has a risk_total =< 1000 
  date_complete = Date.today
end
```

The code looks like as follows.

```
    def validate_completion
if self.date_completed.nil?
  if self.Biohaz_exist == "No"
    if self.Hazmat_exist == "No"
      if self.Fire_exist == "No"
        if self.Hazengy_exist == "No"
          if self.Tool_exist == "No"
            if self.Rad_exist == "No"
              if self.Laz_exist == "No"
                if self.Mag_exist == "No"
                  if self.Ergo_exist == "No"
                    if self.Mechand_exist == "No"
                      if self.Road_exist == "No"
                        if self.Fall_exist == "No"
                          if self.Hazatm_exist == "No"
                            if self.Noise_exist == "No"
                              if self.Ovrhead_exist == "No"
                                if self.Cut_exist == "No"
                                  if self.Temp_exist == "No"
                                    if self.Access_exist == "No"
                                      if self.Cowrkr_exist == "No"
                                        if self.Lonewrkr_exist == "No"
                                          self.date_completed = Date.today
                                        elsif self.Biohaz_exist == "Yes" and self.Biohaz.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Hazmat_exist == "Yes" and self.Hazmat.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Fire_exist == "Yes" and self.Fire.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Hazengy_exist == "Yes" and self.Hazengy.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Tool_exist == "Yes" and self.Tool.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Rad_exist == "Yes" and self.Rad.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Laz_exist == "Yes" and self.Laz.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Mag_exist == "Yes" and self.Mag.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Ergo_exist == "Yes" and self.Ergo.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Mechand_exist == "Yes" and self.Ergo.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Road_exist == "Yes" and self.Ergo.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Fall_exist == "Yes" and self.Fall.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Hazatm_exist == "Yes" and self.Hazatm.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Noise_exist == "Yes" and self.Noise.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Ovrhead_exist == "Yes" and self.Ovrhead.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Cut_exist == "Yes" and self.Cut.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Temp_exist == "Yes" and self.Temp.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Access_exist == "Yes" and self.Access.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Cowrkr_exist == "Yes" and self.Cowrk.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil
                                        elsif self.Lonewrkr_exist == "Yes" and self.Lonewrkr.risk_total > 1000
                                          self.date_completed = nil                                                                                  
                                        else
                                          self.date_completed = Date.today  
                                        end
                                      end
                                    end
                                  end
                                end
                              end
                            end
                          end
                        end
                      end
                    end
                  end
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

As is right now if no hazards exist, it successfully sets the date to today. And if I then add a hazard it effectively switches the date back to nil. However, If one hazard exists and it has a risk_total below 1000 the date remains nil.

Comment: how are your hazards defined?  What if you need to add a new hazard, or remove a hazard?  That conditional statement is a nightmare to read, write and maintain.

Comment: hazards are static. They will not be added or removed. Can you suggest an alternate way to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 1):

"Well, given that your hazards are statically defined and not in the database, you could do something like this:

```
#definition of all the hazard
hazards = [:Fire, :Road, :Fall]
def validate_completion
  # find all the hazards that exist
  exists = hazards.select { |hazard| self.send("#{hazard.to_s}_exist") } 
  # find if at least one high risk hazard exists
  high_risk_total = exists.detect {|hazard| self.send("#{hazard.to_s}_risk_total") > 1000 }
  # find if at least one low rick hazard exists
  low_risk_total = exists.detect {|hazard| self.send("#{hazard.to_s}_risk_total") <= 1000 }

  # validation logic here
end
```

**You can get by with this logic, but it might be significantly easier to make your hazards a database table and use ActiveRecord associations and queries to simplify this.**

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am very new to RoR and i've yet to see code quite like this. For the validation logic, what exactly are the outputs of these variables? How would I check to see if for example none exist?

Comment: Also, It won't tell me the specifics for some reason in the log other than there is a problem with that code. can this code be run like this in the model? It doesn't seem to work.